# Android Non removable shortcut

Tags: android

Is there a way to create a homescreen shortcut that can not be removed progromatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to prevent a particular homescreen shortcut from being removed programatically.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to guarantee that a shortcut could not be removed, the best guarantee would be to create your own homescreen. If you went that route you could even integrate the shortcut better than a normal shortcut.

The above solution would be a great implementation if you were providing a device to employees and didn't want them to accidentally delete an important shortcut. What is your use case for this? We could provide a better solution with more details.

Comment: This answer should come with a gigantic disclaimer: not a trivial solution.

Answer (score -1):

I think that this post might can be useful, hope it will help.

[Trying to UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT but shortcut won't go away](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480287/trying-to-uninstall-shortcut-but-shortcut-wont-go-away)

Comment: Ops, misunderstood the question...sorry.