# Android remove shortcuts in HomeScreen

Tags: android, shortcut, homescreen

How to remove shortcuts in the home screen(programatically). I can remove the shortcuts created by me using intent but not other existing ones..

```
Bitmap theBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)icon).getBitmap();

        Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent();
        shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);


  shortcutIntent.setClassName(url, group);

   shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

   Intent removeIntent = new Intent();
   removeIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
   removeIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, name);
   removeIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false);
   removeIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON, theBitmap);
   removeIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT");

   sendBroadcast(removeIntent);
```

when deleting using intent as above, it is possible to delete shortcut when knowing the icon packagename + app class name. we can get icon package name of all application using PackageInfo as follows but not the launch class name

```
ArrayList<PInfo> res = new ArrayList<PInfo>();        
        List<PackageInfo> packs = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
        for(int i=0;i<packs.size();i++) {
            PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);



            if ((!getSysPackages) && (p.versionName == null)) {
                continue ;
            }
            PInfo newInfo = new PInfo();
            newInfo.appname = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
            newInfo.pname = p.packageName;
            newInfo.classname = p.applicationInfo.className;
            newInfo.versionCode = p.versionCode;
            newInfo.icon = p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager());
```

Now problem is, Is there any method to get class name of a application, then we can delete the shortcut created by this application in the home Screen.. any help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot remove programatically other shortcuts from homescreen

Comment: Source or anything? I found samples from developers which were able to delete other shortcuts. BUT as CommonsWare said: "There is no requirement for any home screen implementation to support [uninstall_shortcut] [...]"

Comment: I changed my mind. You are simply wrong and this answer should not be accepted! I did it 5 minutes before.

I will add some links and code as an answer.

Answer (score 6):

**It IS possible.**

**[UPDATE]:** Since **Android M**,  they've completely removed support for the UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT intent in AOSP Launcher3 and Google Now Launcher. Currently there is no alternative or replacement for this API.
Source: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=179697

---

**[UPDATE-2]**: Maybe this is helpful for some of you. I was able to figure out, how - at least- to uninstall *my apps own* shotscuts from the home screen. While Google removed the support for the uninstall of a shortcut, a shortcut, that points to an activity-alias will still get removed, once the alias is disabled.

*Small reference:*

```
   ComponentName yourAlias = new ComponentName(getPackageName(), "org.example.yourAliasName");

    if (show){
        flag = PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED;
    }else{
        flag = PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED;
    }


    context.getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(yourAlias, flag, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

---

**Below Android M:**

First things first, here the code which I was repeatedly able to delete the Facebook shortcut, 
**without** any root (which is kind of the same like op's code, so he was *not* wrong):

```
    Intent appIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    appIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.facebook.katana", "com.facebook.katana.LoginActivity"));
    appIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

    Intent addIntent = new Intent("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "Facebook");
    addIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false);
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, appIntent);

    sendBroadcast(addIntent);
```

The important thing is, that your intent must be exaclty the same, as the Intent which
was used to create the shortcut. You can, if you have root, take a look into the 
**launcher.db** and copy the URI.
Located in `data/data/com.android.Launcher.launcher.db` 
However, you don't have access to the android launcher.db
anytime, so it can be a bit try and error.

Sources which I highly recommend to read:

[UninstallShortcutReceiver.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher/+/master/src/com/android/launcher/UninstallShortcutReceiver.java)

[very good answer from Dev-il for this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480287/trying-to-uninstall-shortcut-but-shortcut-wont-go-away/)

Additonally, code to fetch all applications and their data, which in my
case was enough to remove most of the shortcuts.

```
PackageManager pManager = context.getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> packageInfos = loadApps(context);
```

From here you can iterate over the list and fetch necessary information's like:

```
ActivityInfo activityInfo = packInfo.activityInfo;
```

- activityInfo.loadLabel(pManager).toString() `//name of the App`
- activityInfo.loadIcon(pManager) `//Icon of the activity as drawable`
- activityInfo.packageName `// packageName the activity belongs to`
- activityInfo.name `//Launcher class name`

Answer (score 0):

Use the following method:

```
    private void removeShortcutIcon(String app_name, Intent app_intent){
    app_intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    app_intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    Intent removeIntent = new Intent();
    removeIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, app_intent);
    removeIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, app_name);
    removeIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    removeIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT");
    getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(removeIntent);
}
```

And try to get all installed apps in the following way:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> pacs_list = pm.queryIntentActivities(main_intent, 0);
for(int i=0; i < pacs_list.size(); i++)
{
pacs_list.get(i).loadIcon(pm);
pacs_list.get(i).activityInfo.packageName;
pacs_list.get(i).loadLabel(pm).toString();
}
```

Note: you can get various attributes from ResolveInfo. Check this link: [ResolveInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ResolveInfo.html)