# Uninstall shortcut isn't removed

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to combine these two answers:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22137880/2746924

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7461521/2746924

Where I store the Uri and then parse it later again in order to uninstall the shortcut. However using the following good the shortcut remains in place.

This is the uri i store:

```
String shortcutUri = shortcutIntent.toUri(0);
```

This is how I attempt to remove the shortcut:

```
private static void removeShortcut(String appPackage, String appName, String oldShortcutUri) {

    Intent shortcutIntent = null;

    try {
        shortcutIntent = Intent.parseUri(oldShortcutUri, 0);
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Intent addIntent = new Intent();

    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, appName);
    addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT");

    MainApplication.getAppContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);
}
```

The appName is identical and the shortcutIntent parses without throwing exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem. There is a very popular tutorial on web, which explains how to install or uninstall shortcuts. Even some stackoverflow answers are just copy-pastes of that tutorial. If you have followed that tutorial,this is probably why you can't uninstall the shortcut:

Do NOT forget to add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
```

to your manifest. Many people forget it since the tutorial itself tells you to add permission for installing a shortcut but doesn't mention the permission you need to uninstall it.

Comment: You should share the link of the tutorial.