# Android shortcut can not remove in other app instance

Tags: android, shortcut

I am trying to add/remove shortcut for my app. The "add" code works perfect. But removing works only if I run it at the same app instance it was created. If I create the shortcut, then restart app and finally execute the "remove" code it fails (don't remove the icon).

This is my code:

```
public static void add(Class<? extends Activity> activity, String name, Bitmap icon) {
    Context context = ...;

    icon = scaleIcon(context, icon);

    Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(context, activity);
    shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    int flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT;
    shortcutIntent.setFlags(flags);

    Intent addIntent = new Intent();
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, name);
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON, icon);
    addIntent.setAction(SHORTCUT_INSTALL);

    context.sendBroadcast(addIntent);
}

public static void remove(Class<? extends Activity> activity, String name) {
    Context context = ...;

    Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(context, activity);
    shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    int flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT;
    shortcutIntent.setFlags(flags);

    Intent removeIntent = new Intent(SHORTCUT_UNINSTALL);
    removeIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
    removeIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, name);

    context.sendBroadcast(removeIntent);
}
```

BTW, I couldn't find android docs about shortcuts.
Thanks for helping me.

Comment: is there any error you see in logcat?

Comment: Check this same question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480287/trying-to-uninstall-shortcut-but-shortcut-wont-go-away probably the answers there may help you

Comment: I checked that answer and It didn't help me. I couldn't find a solution after a exhaustive research.

Comment: Logcat doesn't show an error.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add this permission:

```
<uses-permission
        android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
```

[Source](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/android-install-uninstall-shortcut-example/)

Comment: I've already added the permission. It works at the same app instance, so it may not be a problem.

Comment: are you using a custom ROM? try on a different device and see if you get the same issue

Comment: I am using a real and common device.