# Hide application shortcut

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

I am trying to make an application of which I am trying to hide the launcher shortcut. The reason for this is so I could use this apps as a module / extension for another app without it being visible or cluttering the launcher environment (ie. having this app on your phone will unlock partial functionality in another app). I have been looking into how to do this for a while now, but I can't find a proper solution.

I have read a 'solution' to this issue that tells me to remove `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />` from the `AndroidManifest.xml` file. This however results in Android Studio not being able to build or run the app at all, giving me an error that says `Default Activity not found` (I have tried this with a fresh project and an empty activity).

I am trying to develop this app on my personal device which is a Huawei P9 Lite, running android 6.0

Is there a way to do this?

### EDIT

I've read [somewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33731620/1448061) that Google has removed the ability to uninstall shortcuts since android 6.0. Although it doesn't really say anything about hiding shortcuts for your application, I went ahead and assumed it's part of the same security fix.

Is there a way to do this for the newest platform versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have read a 'solution' to this issue that tells me to remove  from the AndroidManifest.xml file.

That is the correct answer.

> This however results in Android Studio not being able to build or run the app at all, giving me an error that says Default Activity not found (I have tried this with a fresh project and an empty activity).

Well, it may not make sense to run it. After all, you say that this app is a plugin to some other app. In many cases, a plugin itself cannot run independently (e.g., you cannot run a browser plugin except via the hosting browser).

That being said, you can edit your run configuration via Run > Edit Configurations, and choose what you want to have happen when you run the module:

[image: Run Configuration Dialog]

The run configuration for an app module defaults to "Default Activity", but you can choose something else (e.g., "Specific Activity").

> I've read somewhere that Google has removed the ability to uninstall shortcuts since android 6.0.

That answer is unrelated to your question.