# How to remove pinned shortcuts?

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, pinned-shortcut

### Background

Starting from Android O, it's possible to create pinned shortcuts, which (on supported launchers) show a dialog to confirm the creation of them:

```
            ShortcutInfoCompat pinShortcutInfo = new ShortcutInfoCompat.Builder(context, uniqueShortcutId)
                    .setShortLabel(label)
                    .setIntent(shortcutIntent)
                    .setLongLabel(label)
                    .setIcon(IconCompat.createWithBitmap(bitmap))
                    .build();
            ShortcutManagerCompat.requestPinShortcut(this, pinShortcutInfo , null);
```

Docs:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ShortcutManager.html
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts.html

### The problem

Sometimes, the pinned shortcut is not relevant anymore. For example, it points to something that doesn't exist anymore.

In this case, I want to be able to remove it.

### What I've tried

I thought this is possible by the next code, but it doesn't, because it is probably about dynamic shortcuts, which is something else :

```
ShortcutManager shortcutManager = (ShortcutManager) getSystemService(SHORTCUT_SERVICE);
final List<ShortcutInfo> pinnedShortcuts = shortcutManager.getPinnedShortcuts();
final ArrayList<String> shortcutIdsToRemove = new ArrayList<>();
for (ShortcutInfo pinnedShortcut : pinnedShortcuts) {
    final Intent pinnedShortcutIntent = pinnedShortcut.getIntent();
    shortcutIdsToRemove.add(pinnedShortcut.getId());
}
shortcutManager.removeDynamicShortcuts(shortcutIdsToRemove);
// this also doesn't work : shortcutManager.disableShortcuts(shortcutIdsToRemove);
```

### The question

How can I remove pinned shortcuts? Is it even possible?

---

Update: seems it isn't possible, as Google mentioned [**here**](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68949561#comment4).

So far, this API seems very restricting to me, as it has so many disadvantages:

1. The created icon image cannot be created from a resource ID.
2. On the launcher, the created icon has a tiny icon of the app that created it.
3. The icon cannot be removed via the API (only disabled), so if you created one that points to another app, and this app was removed, you won't be able to remove it.
4. The creation cannot be in the background, as it requires a confirmation dialog. It also cannot be created in a batch. Only one after another.
5. All pinned shortcuts your app has created will be removed if your app was removed.

So, my question now is:

1. Is there any way to create and remove a shortcut using the previous API, using an adb command, with root if needed ?
2. Is it possible to remove specific pinned shortcuts using adb command , with root if needed?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @AlexandruPetrescu No. Sadly no...

Comment: @AlexandruPetrescu I have given what I believe to be the best possible answer to this question. Please review it and award the bounty before the grace period expires.

Answer (score 4):

[disableShortcuts()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ShortcutManager#disableShortcuts(java.util.List%3Cjava.lang.String%3E)) is the best you can do. It will show the user a custom error message when they try to select the disabled shortcut.

From the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts/):

> Shortcut limitations
>   Although you can publish up to five shortcuts (static and dynamic shortcuts combined) at a time for your app, most launchers can only display four.
>
> However, there is no limit to the number of pinned shortcuts to your app that users can create. Even though your app cannot remove pinned shortcuts, it can still disable them.

[Another section](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts/managing-shortcuts#disable-shortcuts):

> Because your app and its users can pin shortcuts to the device's launcher, it's possible that these pinned shortcuts could direct users to actions within your app that are out of date or no longer exist. To manage this situation, you can disable the shortcuts that you don't want users to select by calling disableShortcuts(), which removes the specified shortcuts from the static and dynamic shortcuts list and disables any pinned copies of these shortcuts. You can also use an overloaded version of this method, which accepts a CharSequence as a custom error message. That error message then appears when users attempt to launch any disabled shortcut.
>
> Note: If you remove some of your app's static shortcuts when you update your app, the system disables these shortcuts automatically.

Comment: Disabling is quite useless. The user sees a shortcut he can no longer use, so why have it... Do you know of a rooted way perhaps for this, or for creating&removing of shortcuts using the old API ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper is it really worth it to restrict your app to root users for that capability? Your disabled message could simply state "This functionality is no longer available. Shortcut may be deleted manually." -- and the user can do it themselves.

Comment: @androiddeveloper also, even if you wanted to do this with root, you would need to handle the delete differently for every possible launcher you wanted to support. The system doesn't hold the shortcut data, the launcher does.

Comment: I meant creating&deletion via the previous API. I think that somehow installing apps from the Play Store creates shortcuts using an API that doesn't request confirmation from the user. Maybe it's the old one somehow. This is also why many launchers have an option to put shortcuts for newly installed apps, but it works only if installing them from the Play Store, and not if you install via a normal APK file.

Comment: @androiddeveloper the play store has special permissions granted to it. It can also automatically enable the "draw on top of other apps" permission, which you have to enable manually for apps installed from anywhere else.

AFAIK, there is not even a deprecated API for deleting a shortcut. Shortcuts are only deleted when app data is cleared, so you could try imitating an "app uninstall" system broadcast, which will cause the launcher to delete ALL of your app's shortcuts (which you cold try to add back). In short, this is a bad idea and you shouldn't do it.

Comment: @androiddeveloper also, I would appreciate if you would award me the bounty before the grace period ends. sorry there isn't a reasonable way to do what you want!

Comment: I can't. It's not me who have put the bounty. I've given up on this question a long time ago, seeing that I've failed to find a solution for non-rooted ones, except for things you've already written. But when you started answering, I was hoping you'd at least have a solution for rooted devices. If you have a solution that causes the app shortcut to appear (maybe as if it was from the Play Store) , it would be great. If you find such a solution (and show that it works, of course), I will put a new bounty and grant it.

Comment: @androiddeveloper No, I do not have an interest in solving this problem, as I believe that it would create an inherently bad user experience. If you are interested in researching it yourself, you'll have to read the android source code.

Comment: Well, the question was about solving it, with or without root... You answered the part of without it. I believe that the bad user experience is when the user has a shortcut that points to nothing, hence having junk shortcuts.

Comment: @androiddeveloper an icon suddenly missing from a user's home screen is certainly a poor UX. Also, solving this with root will not be a pretty piece of code. You must understand that the data for each shortcut is located within the private data of the launcher itself. So, for every launcher you need to open their closed source format for data storage, and edit that data. Do you see why this is a terrible idea?

Comment: That's incorrect. That's how it has always been when an app gets removed. If the target of the shortcut is invalid and can't be reached due to removal of the app, it should be removed automatically too. The root question is not just about pinned shortcuts but also about those that the Play Store creates (though it could be nice to know if that's possible too), so it's not related to code of launchers. It's a great idea to remove shortcuts of removed apps. That's how it works with normal apps that the user install from the Play Store, but not from normal APKs.

Comment: @androiddeveloper the launchers remove the installed app's icon via a broadcast receiver that triggers on app uninstall intents, or by iterating through the list of installed apps and discovering that it is not there. There is likely an easy way to add a shortcut via root, since the play store already does it via an existing system feature. However, there is not going to be an easy way to remove a specific shortcut, since the only built in system feature for doing that depends on broadcasting an uninstall, which would remove ALL the target app's shortcuts.

Comment: What is the way to create a shortcut like the Play Store does, using root?

Comment: @androiddeveloper I poked around at the AOSP source code for a bit, and it looks like the answer is different for different API levels. I would start by trying to use `com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT`, but that's only for the stock launcher. You may have to decompile the Play Store and see what the are doing on install. Furthermore, this behavior is changed in newer versions of Android, and the Play Store no longer directly handles this, and it is up to each individual launcher to create a broadcast receiver for `ACTION_SESSION_COMMITTED`.

Comment: @androiddeveloper Lastly, here is how you can delete a shortcut on the home screen (and as I warned before, it is very hacky, and specific to only one launcher): https://stackoverflow.com/a/22137880/2301185

Comment: This permission is said to be deprecated and can't be used, so I don't think the Play Store uses it on new Android versions. And once you create a shortcut of the app, it's not related to hacking anymore, because the launcher monitors the app, so that when it gets uninstalled, the shortcut is automatically removed. No need for hacks and even any coding. Please, if you find out how to create a shortcut like on the Play Store (using root if needed, but without being a system app), let me know. I will put a new bounty and grant it (if you show it works).

Comment: @androiddeveloper Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182948/discussion-between-blufenix-and-android-developer).