# Change Android app icons in APK?

Tags: android

Is it possible to change the app icon in an APK in Android apps? I have a tablet running Android 2.2 and the icons are too low-res, so I want to replace them. I tried unzipping the APK, changing the icon and re-zipping, but it didn't work. Is there any way I can change the icon, even programmatically, to reflect the higher-res icon?

Comment: I think you want to change icons of third-party owned application, if it is right then i think its not possible.

Comment: Do you have access to root folder??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

APK files are actually nothing more than zip files. If you just want to replace images, then the easiest way is to open the apk file in 7-zip or winrar and replace the png files in there with your own. Just drag your new files to the 7-zip window.

Note that I said "open" and not "unzip". Once you decompress it, the signature will no longer be valid.

Another option is to use [APKManager](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=695701) to do it. This way you do not need to install it in /system/app:

1. Download APK Manager
2. Put the .apk in "place-apk-here-for-modding"
3. Run the script.bat and extract it.
4. Drop the new PNG files in /res/drawable-?dpi overwriting the old ones.
5. Run ZIP .apk and select option 2 Regular APK
6. Sign the APK
7. Install

Comment: Are you sure the signature won't be invalid if some file is replaced(with out decompression) by 7-zip?

Answer (score 7):

### Summary

One the simplest ways is to change APK icons via user-friendly GUI tools:

- [APK Editor Studio](https://qwertycube.com/apk-editor-studio/) – advanced but still easy-to-use APK editor.
- [APK Icon Editor](https://qwertycube.com/apk-icon-editor/) – plain and simple APK editor.

Both tools are free and [open-source](https://github.com/kefir500/apk-editor-studio) (written in C++/Qt) with the Apktool used under the hood.

### Features

- Automatically pack, sign and optimize your APK.
- Automatic conversion between PNG, BMP, JPEG, ICO, GIF, etc.
- Available for **Windows**, **macOS** and **Linux**.

[image: APK Icon Editor]

### Disclaimer

I am the author of these tools.

Comment: Please, try to read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers, to get more understanding how to **not** answer. Namely: "Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question": **barely more than a link to an external site**

Comment: Please stop enforcing stackoverflow rules.

Comment: @StefanReich This post directly answers the OP's question (which excludes the spamming nature) and contains an explicit disclaimer (which excludes the improper promotion). See [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260641/2004438) for more info. Also, the issues pointed out by Radim Köhler were fixed back in 2014. If you do not agree, you can always raise the moderator flag.

Answer (score 3):

If you want change android application icon programatically then you can set it into AndroidManifest.xml file, in the application tag by setting the **android:icon property**. But if you want to change the icon of third party applications then you cant.

Answer (score 2):

See this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android)

Comment: so basically it isnt possible?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this one for designing icons for high, medium and low density phones: 
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_launcher.html