# Programmatically changing the icon/label for an Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

Is it possible to change the icon and label for an Activity programmatically?

We have a requirement (handed down from On High, don't blame me) to update the icon that one of our app's Activities shows in the Recent Tasks list depending on what the application is doing. Does anyone know if this is actually possible?

Comment: certainly an interesting idea (although I can imagine it causing some confusion for the end user).

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps a bit: [How to change an application icon programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android)