# Set application label in java code instead in AndroidManifes

Tags: android, label, android-manifest, title

Is it possible to set label for application in java code instead in AndroidManifes, I mean the displayable name of application not just title of activity.

Comment: Are you trying to change the name of your application, as it appears on the phone's home/applications screen, at runtime?

Comment: Yes... I need some kind of possibilites of customization.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can, as per the [answer to this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android).

Comment: Robert is having different problem, i think he want to set the application name programmatically, is it right robert?