# Android how to programmatically hide launcher icon

Tags: android, icons, launcher

my app is designed to only need to be run once. As such I want to hide the icon from the launcher after the first run, but without uninstalling the app.

I have seen similar applications - they can remove their own icons from the launcher app list. How can I achieve the same results? Thank you.

Comment: Never seen that to be honest, out of curiosity: Can you name one or two apps that do that?

Comment: i'm curious too , plz name one or two apps which can remove their own icons from the launcher app list. thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android

Comment: Unfortunately I forgot which application but I'll reply here if I come across it again...

Comment: The application is "Smart Keyboard Pro". In its settings, there is an option to remove the launcher icon.

Answer (score 65):

```
PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
p.setComponentEnabledSetting(getComponentName(), PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Note that the icon may not be gone until the next reboot.

Comment: Thanks, but if I use this, will I be able to update my application via Market?

Comment: Yes I use this myself in one of my own apps.

Comment: then how do you define a shortkey to actually launch your app

Comment: when i do this and try to reinstall my app , its not working. It says activity (the one disbaled) doesnot exist. Can you please help how to handle it

Comment: OP, kindly accept one of the answers as they seem to solve your problem

Comment: How can I call this in a different activity to the one I want to disable?

Comment: Hi @Kuffs This solution really works, but my app cannot Received a GCM message. How can my app receive GCM message even if the icon laucher is hidden?

Comment: @Kuffs i had used this method and open applcation when message receive menac in brodcast recerver i had open application but when i used this code to hide app and recever start activity it's crase that activity not found while without code when message receve it's perfectly open. can u help me?

Comment: I am also facing the same problem as @pintu

Comment: @SHIVANGSANGHI once you hide apps it will destroy that activity so you need to open another activity when you open it

Comment: It does not allows the application to run further... seems it is killing the app

Comment: I really taught this was more complicated but this answer worked flawlessly. NOTE: Problems caused by this when you try to uninstall is because your only exported component (activity marked with main and launcher) is disabled by this. You can add some other exported component to get back into the app (for example register broadcast receiver for GCM or SMS receive). Similar approach needs to be done to re-enable re-installing from play store (and even from eclipse) but I am not certain what component needs to be added.

Answer (score 13):

Hide app's icon using below code

```
PackageManager pkg=this.getPackageManager();
pkg.setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(this,SplashActivity.class),PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                        PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

// activity which is first time open in manifiest file which is declare as `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />`

Here is how to bring back the app's icon

```
PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this,SplashActivity.class);
p.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Answer (score 10):

With Android Q (API 29) [Google changed the Launcher icon visibility](https://web.archive.org/web/20190829024136/https://developer.android.com/preview/release-notes#launcher-icon-visibility-beta2) behaviour. Even if you disable your Launcher Activity or completely remove the 
*android.intent.category.LAUNCHER* `<intent-filter>` from all your Activities, the app will appear in the launcher and open the Android OS app settings, with the exception of:

- Packages that don't declare any permissions in their respective manifest files
- System apps
- Apps that don't contain any components inside their
  respective manifest's  tag

Answer (score 1):

You can have an app without a launcher by NOT including an intent filter with MAIN and LAUNCHER in the declaration of the Activity in the AndroidManifest - the question then becomes how to do the first kick off.. Widget maybe ?

Comment: I don't think OP meant the icon that is created "on the desktop", but rather the icon in the "app drawer". Also.. maybe you can open it using the "open" button in the play store after installing.

Answer (score 1):

Hide app icon using this code:

```
PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, com.apps.MainActivity.class); // activity which is first time open in manifiest file which is declare as <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
p.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

and bring it back, with this:

```
PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, com.apps.MainActivity.class);
p.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

**NOTE:** This will not work for Android 10

Comment: is there any possibility for android 10 hide icon with admin permission or like this ?