# Block acces to other apps in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, parental-control

Good evening, I am a student from Spain, developing an app in java about sports, that when it's time to workout it prohibits you to use other apps (such as candy crush, facebook...) until you finish it. I don't know how to translate this in code or even if it's possible.

I think it's not illegal, as long as you ask for permission from the user before installing?

I've seen some apps like parental control apps that do a similar thing, and I think it's the same, am I right?

Comment: If you are asking whether what you are proposing to do is 1) legal or 2) permitted by Google, then both of those questions are not programming questions.  Therefore they are off-topic.  If you are asking us how to code it, that is too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Alex it is possible just start a service  when your app starts and check package name according to your prohibited lists 
 [visit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32822101/how-to-programmatically-open-the-permission-screen-for-a-specific-app-on-android)
 [also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11453814/block-unblock-an-application-from-my-application-android)
and when app closed stop the service.