# How to Hide app from launcher in Android

Tags: show-hide, launcher, android

I am developing an android app. I want to hide the app icon from launcher.
Then show it again if some specific no from dialer is typed. Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
p.setComponentEnabledSetting(getComponentName(),
    PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, 
    PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

& check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134884/android-how-to-programmatically-hide-launcher-icon) link. Note that the icon may not be gone until the next reboot.

**OR**

Try this:

```
PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName("com.google.android.talk",
    "com.google.android.talk.LAUNCHER"),
    PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
    PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Hope this Help.

Comment: I have used this code in launching activity but icon still appears.

Comment: do you have visited the link i have suggested you for reference ?