# Hide application icon from launcher

Tags: android, icons, show-hide, android-launcher

I have an android application.  I want to hide app icon from launcher screen & make it visible again after dialing some no i.e "1234" . 
Any helpful code snippet will be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134884/android-how-to-programmatically-hide-launcher-icon

Comment: why are posting same question multiple times..here is the same question from you..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21847763/how-to-hide-app-from-launcher-in-android

Answer (score 2):

Have a look on this link. May be it will help you

**[hidden App](http://androidsnips.blogspot.in/2011/11/create-android-application-with-no.html?m=0)**

Edit 1:

First:

```
PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
p.setComponentEnabledSetting(getComponentName(), PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Second :

```
public class DialBroad extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);

        if ((phoneNumber).equals("123456")) {
            Intent appIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            appIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(appIntent);
            setResultData(null);
        } else {
            // Toast.makeText(context, phoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that will hide launcher all the time and that is not what is wanted

Comment: okay, than don't do with xml. handle through the Nun Chai but use broadcast for handling through dial pad