# I dont want Launcher icon for my app

Tags: android, android-studio

I dont want Launcher icon for my app but when I am removing.

```
<intent-filter>                
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />                 
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />            
 </intent-filter>
```

even only removing

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

My manifest is as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"

    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <service
        android:name=".ShakeDetectService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" />

    <receiver
        android:name=".MyServiceReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
     </activity>
</application>
```

Android studio is giving error **Error Launching activity** Please give me your valuable suggestion.
Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134884/android-how-to-programmatically-hide-launcher-icon

Comment: Ignore the error message , the application also installed in you phone.

Comment: i have given broadcast receiver to receive BOOT of device.but it is not working.Same broadcast receiver is working when i am giving </intent-filter> in my activity in manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Go to:
1. Run --> Edit Configuration
2. Under your app tab (default opened tab) change the **Launch Options** to **Nothing**

**Note**: your app won't be running after installation without external help (Broadcast messages)

[image]

Comment: i have given broadcast receiver to receive BOOT of device.but it is not working.Same broadcast receiver is working when i am giving </intent-filter> in my activity in manifest.

Comment: Which intent action (filter)?

Comment: ` <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
    <intent-filter>                
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />                 
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />            
   </intent-filter> 
 </activity>`

Answer (score 0):

- open run/debug configurations from android studio
- choose edit
- configurations select your module from left panel from general tab
- choose launch option as -> 'Nothing'