# Cannot start app on boot after hiding launcher icon

Tags: android

The app doesn't want to run on boot when launcher icon are hidden. I hide launcher icon by removing:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

How do I make my app being called on boot even after launcher icon are hidden. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this is useful for you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134884/android-how-to-programmatically-hide-launcher-icon

Comment: @ruitercomp sadly, no

Comment: Do you have a receiver with intent-filter "BOOT_COMPLETED" in your manifest?