# How can I access R.java using inputStream

Tags: android, file, r.java-file

I want access to `R.java` using `InputStream`, in order to get the key of the  resource.

```
File file = new File("gen/com/XX/R.java") ; 
   new FileInputStream(file) ;
```

I had used two file path gen/com/XX/R.java    or   com/XX/R.java
But return `inputStream` object is null. 
Who can tell me `R.java` can access? if can do it, how to do? Can anyone give me some suggestion?
Thanks .

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to access R.java using file objects. it will be dynamic memory location when you run the application. and what thing drives you do read R.java, please share your requirement so we can suggest best possible solution. because you are going on wrong path.

Comment: I have some layout xml file template, the file under res/layout/template.xml

Comment: For example: there have a ImageView in the xml, the ImageView have a unique Id, ImageView default background resource is a.png. I can change it background resource by a configure file(The format： 7f010002=7f010001 <key is the view id and value is resource id>). so I need to get the id,  when I edit the template.xml file, the id may be changed, so I should change the imageView id value in the configure file. if I can get the name of the ImageView and resource (R.id.imagea:use imagea) , when the template file changed,needn't to change configure file

Comment: Oh, you are going totally other direction..you wanted to change the background of the layout correct? if yes you can do it by http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html

Answer (score 0):

From the last three questions I've seen that you are trying to modify the apk. The apk is just a glorified zip file.

And if you are trying to edit it, you're doing it [completely wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1103663/68805).