# Dynamically Updating Launcher Icon in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to put a dynamic value in the launcher icon of android, as number of messages will be displayed in the message icon. As the icon is static and initialised before the application starts, Is there any way to achieve this??

Comment: isn't it simpler to use [push notifications](http://urbanairship.com/products/push-notifications/)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android

Comment: I am using that as well but i am programming for a samsung tablet which has huge icons and its messging application does the same, so was trying to do it for my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Android Launcher Icon you can't. It is impossible. (Or by Making your own launcher) The only one thing is you have to make a [Android-Widget](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/04/introducing-home-screen-widgets-and.html) for this purpose. Which looks like a application icon. But it will act as a widget.

Also [Make a dynamic launcher icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9055836/make-a-dynamic-launcher-icon)

Answer (score 1):

simple answer is [you can't do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9055836/make-a-dynamic-launcher-icon) also this [question says the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android). But there may be advance tricky methods/ways that I'm not aware of.

But you may try and develop [widgets that changes dynamically](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You have to design your icon as a selector instead of drawable. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9603770/application-launcher-icon-to-show-update-is-available).

Answer (score 0):

You cant update because its related to manifest.xml stuff only possible with software upgrade.