# how can i set the application icon programmatically android

Tags: android, icons

I know that we can set it through manifest file using android:icon attribute.But how can we set it in java code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to set it programmatically, the launcher has to display the application icon when the application isn't active.

If you take a look at [How to change an application icon programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android), you will find a comment, which links to this sample code in the Android developer API demos: [LaucherShortcuts](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/LauncherShortcuts.html).

It seams that the Activity can create a LauncherShortcut, which can have a different icon (see function setupShortcut()). If you want the user to select the Icon, you have to display a list of icons when creating the shortcut. But again, it is a shortcut. In the list of application the original icon appears.

Comment: I think the apps that "appear" to change the launcher icon at run time are doing so using a widget rather than a real launcher shortcut.

Comment: @KUFFS:can you some examples so that i can work around that....i have tried to search but failed...

Answer (score 1):

I dont think the launcher icon can be set programatically.