# Changing an app icon on Android

Tags: android, icons

On an android device, is possible to change the app icon after it's already installed? Can it be done from the app itself, by code?
If my app would be written using Sencha Touch, will it change anything?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think it's possible, but it would be nice!

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change the application icon (or the Android manifest, or any other application resource for that matter) once your APK is compiled. The only way to do this is by re-compiling and pushing an update to the market.