# How to create dynamic icon in android like SMS icon

Tags: android, sms

How application launcher icon value increase or decrease in Android as I know the application icons is static but in SMS service when we get message the icon is changed.

How is it possible?
Can anybody tell me what should I do for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change an application icon programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android)