# How to change an application icon programmatically in Android, 2016

Tags: android, application-icon

I, as so many Android programmers before me, would like to change the Icon of my App from the inside. *My App would be a simple WiFi Switch App, with an Icon that displays the state. Yes, WiFi is in the Notification Bar. Byte me, I am lazy.* Anyway, there is not a simple system in place to do so, so it seems.

I have searched, low and shallow (not longer then an hour). And this is what I came up with:

- [2009 - Application Icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android)
- [2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042212/android-application-icon-change) - With 2013 link to how SuperSU does it, same as 2009.
- [2011](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043902/android-application-icons-changes-with-runtime/6043948#6043948) - Nothing new.
- [2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12798571/how-to-create-dynamic-icon-in-android-like-sms-icon/12798633#12798633) - Same as 2009.
- [2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17565307/how-to-display-count-of-notifications-in-app-launcher-icon?noredirect=1&lq=1) - First answer has very good explanation.
- [2014](http://techbirds.in/change-an-application-launcher-icon-and-title-programmatically-in-android/) - Still same as 2009.
- [2016 - Shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38524577/how-can-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android-without-creating) question not solved.

**Question: is there a better / easier way to do so than here in the links? It has been 7 years already!**

Comment: Seems this functionality is more suited to a widget,

Answer (score 2):

The answer from 2013 explains it as it is today. There is still no way to change the launcher icon of an app without using third-party software. I doubt Android will add support for this in the near future, as you can use widgets for this sort of thing already.