# Update launcher icon of an Android app to show notification

Tags: android, notifications, icons

I've read the articles about updating Android application icon when some condition is satisfied, like those showing the number of unread mails and similar, but none of these gives the solution. Here is one discusion about that: [How to change an application icon programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android) but still no concrete solution, is it possible at all? If anybody knows how to achieve this bu changing the application code, please let me know...

Comment: You might be better off making a widget

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but none of these gives the solution

That is because there is no solution.

> is it possible at all?

No.

You can create an app widget that is dynamic, or you can write your own home screen that does whatever it wants in terms of its icons.