# Allow user to change default application icon in Android

Tags: android, icons, manifest

Here's the thing...

I want to allow the user to change the default application icon, which is set in the manifest inside the  tag in the android:icon atribute.

So, how can I do this? Any ideas?

Comment: Probably not in application list, but using AppWidget on launcher screen it is possible, see: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html

Comment: try the next link it can help you.
[the link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android