# Change App Icon And Name From Outside

Tags: android, icons, android-manifest, android-assets

Is there any way that set the application Icon and Name from an external resource such as an image which embedded inside the `assets/` folder in the project?
Or is there any way that let us set icon and name of app without using `AndroidManifest.xml` file?

Comment: No it is not possible . You should send an update and things would change in accordance with `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: This is an old answer here on SO. Not sure if it is valid any more (_or valid at all!_). But see if this works: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15249542/450534. It is only for changing the app icon. But this is only for the icon. The app name **has to** be setup in the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way that set the application Icon and Name from an external resource such as an image which embedded inside the assets/ folder in the project?

No.

> Or is there any way that let us set icon and name of app without using AndroidManifest.xml file?

No.

For your activities, you can override the title and/or icon used in the action bar or title bar, if that is your actual objective. However, you cannot change the values used for things like the home screen launcher icon or your app's entry in the application list in Settings.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible . You should send an update and things would change in accordance with `AndroidManifest.xml` .

So what I will suggest is, to send an update

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. by Using [APKtool](http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/)

Comment: How does it help you to change app icon and name without manifest.xml or you have changed the approach. Also I would suggest you accept the answers so that you may get the right answers with time.

Comment: You are right , but I wanted to change the app name and icon from outside with another program. now I can put my new value inside the new generated.apk file and then resign it with new values for example app name and others resources