# Is it possible Selecting Appicon While Installing on Device?

Tags: android

I need the Same Application With Different Application Icon. So is there any possibility to selecting the Application Icon(User Can Select) while Installing the Application on Device?

Comment: not possible ... but application can have many Activities that can be run from launcher ...

Answer (score 0):

It is not directly clear what You want to do. Do You mean, that a User can choose between some images and then set the image as App icon? I read some, but have not tried it:

[How to change an application icon programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android)