# How to change android application name and icon at runtime?

Tags: android, dynamic, icons, runtime

After installing an android app, is it possible to change app icon and name dynamically(at runtime) when you press a button in the app?

This is the code so far..,

```
getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(

new ComponentName("com.example.badgemaste", "com.example.badgemaste.MainActivity"),

                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);


            try {
getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(
                           new ComponentName("com.example.badgemaste", "com.example.badgemaste.MainActivity-One"), 
                                               PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                               //handle
                            }
```

And in the manifest file...

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name2"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.badgemaste.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity-alias
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_laun" 
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:name="com.example.badgemaste.MainActivity-One"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:targetActivity="com.example.badgemaste.MainActivity">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity-alias> 



    </application>
```

When I run this code, initially first icon will appear (in drawer and also in action bar) and then after I close the app and re-run it, it will switch to the other icon.

What I want to do is, assign this procedure to a button, that is if I only press that button, icon will change, otherwise no. 
How can I achieve this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that you're able to change the activity using PackageManager, just Create a button and put the code in it's OnClick.

If this is working, so should that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17146728/how-to-change-app-icon-dynamically-in-android?answertab=active#tab-top