# Change the name of the application Android Studio

Tags: android

Hello I have a problem in calling the name of the application

[image]

I need to invoke the application of MainActivity name `<String xxx>`

```
<resources>
     <string name="app">@layout/activity_main/@xxx</string>
</resources>
```

Is this possible
I do not want to use

```
<string name="app">name</string>
```

Comment: what you are trying to do is completely wrong and not possible

Comment: Can you please try to explain what you are trying to achieve it is a bit difficult to understand from your description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got it wrong. It is actually the opposite way.

In `strings.xml` you declare:

```
<string name="app">Application name</string>
```

An in the activity you read:

```
getString(R.string.app);
```

Comment: But when the application is installed, the following name will appear Application name I want to call the name of the variable text MainActivity Is this thing is possible or not.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to change the application name during runtime??

Comment: Yes, I want to change the name of the application during installation on the phone, but I need the name of the application was summoned private String xxx

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24345068/how-to-change-android-application-name-and-icon-at-runtime