# Change app name and icon run time with user input android

Tags: android

I am trying to change application name at run time with user provided text and app icon with user selected icon . Is it possible to change app name and icon run time ??

I have already tried :
`getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting`

But this is not the perfect solution. Can anyone help me ??

Comment: Have you tried to change the app name through gradle? for appicon, I think that changing through android manifest is already perfect

Edit: I think I missed the "runtime", I don't think you can change that once the app is build though

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17147381/1993446

Comment: how to change app name through gradle ?? i want to set app name whatever user enters in textArea at runtime