# Changing Flutter App Icon Dynamically via HTTP Request

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile-application

I'm working on a mobile app developed using Flutter and Dart, targeting both iOS and Android platforms. In our app, we aim to implement a feature that allows us to dynamically change the app's icon based on user-specific branding information. Unlike common solutions where the icon is stored within the codebase, we need to fetch the icon dynamically through an HTTP request.

While I've come across various solutions and posts detailing how to change the app icon by embedding icons within the codebase, I'm seeking guidance on achieving this functionality by pulling the app icon via an HTTP request and subsequently saving it to the user's device.

To provide a bit of context, our app serves users from different companies, each with their own distinct branding. After users log in, we'd like the app icon to seamlessly switch to the corresponding company's icon. The challenge lies in avoiding the manual addition of icons to the codebase whenever a new company is onboarded, as this approach proves to be cumbersome and impractical.

I found various 6+ year old posts stating this is not possible:

- [How to change APP icon dynamically in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17146728/how-to-change-app-icon-dynamically-in-android)
- [Can I change app icon programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042275/can-i-change-app-icon-programmatically)

I fear this is still not possible today?

Comment: It is not possible on iOS. The icons need to be included in the app bundle.