# How to show notification number in Android Application Launcher icon

Tags: android

I want to show notification number icon in Android application launcher icon. I read about widgets.But how can I show that widget instead of application icon.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to change launcher icon. You can use it for your purpose.

[How to change an application icon programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android)

Comment: But how it changes the icon. Sorry i didn't get the code

Comment: @user1767260 as far as I can understand, you should enable one activity alias at time, so the one with needed icon is used as "MAIN" and is is been shown as launcher icon

Comment: What is this .MainActivity-Red in the code

Comment: @user1767260 it is an activity-alias name

Comment: But where it is changing the launcher icon. Suppose if i get a notification from GCM.How can I show that in my launcher icon

Comment: @user1767260 you create two activity-alias, one with "has notification" icon and one with "no notification". Then, after message is recivied you enable the first one and disable the second. I think it should work.

Comment: In this case I can display only two icons but I want to show the number of notification in the icon.So according to this i have to create a number of alias for showing the count.right?

Comment: @user1767260 I think yes - that's the limitation of this approach.

Comment: Thank you.But it very difficult to implement in my case