# Sony smallapp: how to change icon dynamically

Tags: android, icons, sony

I know how to change icon for the activity using activity alias (see this topic [How to change an application icon programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android)). However, my goal is to change the small app icon, not the activity one. Since sony small app is not an Activity subclass and there is no Service-alias in manifest - this solution does not fit. Is it possible to change the sony smallapp icon dynamically from the code?

Comment: Did you ever manage this?