# Switching between app icons programmatically in android

Tags: android, icons

I have two different variants of an app with slightly different behavior. They share the same code, but the different behavior is through property files in the same project. I would like to have different icons for the apps.

Is there a way for me to change this programmatically? I have two sets of icons images in res/drawable-* folders, one for each app variant.

I've already looked at [How to change an application icon programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android?rq=1), but that seems to be addressing a slightly different issue.

Comment: The accepted answer for the question you linked to seems to be exactly what you are asking. What part of it doesn't seem to fit for your needs?

Comment: I looked at it a little more closely and it didn't work like I expected it to. It basically produced two app icons, but they displayed the same behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you, then you have an app, which functionality depends on a config file, and you want to have two different icon for the two installation of the app.

In this case, you have to change the package name, if you want to have these apps to be installed simultaneously. If so, you could change the icon manually too.

In any other case, **you cannot change the icon of an application in running time.**

Comment: Yeah, this has been my experience too. I just manually changed the icon for each version in the manifest file.

Comment: This is weird. According to the answers in question PO linked, the icon can be changed, though those methods are not working for me. Don't know why those answers got so many upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ActionBarSherlock, try this:

```
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_two);
```

If not, try this:

```
getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_ic_launcher_two);
```