# Can I change the application name (android:label at manifest) or icon (android:icon at manifest) dynamically?

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

Can I do this using Java?

I'm refering to

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
```

in the Android Manifest

If not can I at least provide alternatives that the user can choose from?

Answer (score 1):

Look at [this and the asker references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19161877/switching-between-app-icons-programmatically-in-android).

With th references of the asker, you can see that they put a solution, but if you see the comments, it doesn't work in all devices.

So, it's like the guy answered later, **you cannot change the icon of an application in running time**.

*If you take a look at Facebook Messenger app, it shows you in its icon how many messenges you didn't read yet. I don't know if it works with all devices, but probably not.*