# Change app name, shortcut label and icon after installation. Is it possible?

Tags: android, apk

I need to end a dispute with my customer.

Is it possible to rename the application label, the shortcut name and the application icon after the APK is installed?

I would say no! absolutely no!

No rooted device, no external tool. The application is downloaded and isntalled by the standard Google Play market tool.

At the first execution the app know its new label/icon but it can't modify these properties itself.

Am I wrong?

Comment: There's no way to do this. You will have to build it again in order to rename the application.

Comment: [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zeronoiseapps.secretvideorecorder&hl=en) somehow manages to change the icon .. wonder how though ..

Comment: Oh thanks! I'll try. So someone can change the icon. Good!

Comment: @Seraphim so it seems :).. Good luck

Comment: @Rat-a-tat-a-tatRatatouille Link is broken

Comment: Not a regular app, but System apps do that. E.g. Clock app in MI phones - com.android.deskclock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not wrong sir.

The app's name and icon are stated in the manifest and cannot be changed during runtime. Android does not permit this.

You can, however, change the title of the app in the title bar via `setTitle(name);`

Hope you won some cash over this bet :)

Comment: Unfortunatelly my OEM application need more customization but I think I need to publish the same app with another name (and resources).

Comment: One of the apps we're working on here needs to be reskinned for various potential customers, given different strings, resources, sometimes even different features. when we do this, we duplicate the original code, repack it, and publish it to the app store under a different app signature, icon and name.

Comment: Thanks, it's a very usefull comment! Do you do the same thing for iOS?

Comment: Well, with iOS you can use Targets. You can define different plists & assets (xibs, pngs, etc) in each target, so it makes everything a lot easier. While Apple's publishing procedure is a pain in the neck, (and a little gestapo if you ask me), at least this process is a little easier than Android.

Comment: Yes, and I'm afraid about the iOS review procedure. Do you think the review process will reject the other app because it quite identical to the other app I've just published? Does the "gestapo" part of your comment refer to this eventuality?

Comment: I've published about 10 different skins of the same app in the app store and i'm yet to get rejected for that reason. I did get a reject once simply stating "the app's ui didn't feel intuitive enough". We just republished without changing anything and it got accepted. Of course, this process is spanned over about 3 weeks. I suppose the app reviewer was just in a bad mood that day. There is no guideline that says you can't submit reskinned apps for different clients.

Comment: Hope never dies but Apple is wasting my time... thanks anyway!

Comment: yea, they're the worst :)

Comment: @GilMoshayof i am not really sure if its possible. but then there is an android app in the market (one of the free video recorders) that does change the app icon .. please have a look [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zeronoiseapps.secretvideorecorder&hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searches I found this:

[How to change an application icon programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android)

So it seems to be possible.