# I want to let the user define the name of my app

Tags: android, sqlite

I have app and i want the user to name it i want to give him some names and let him choose the name he want as app_name 
how to do it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change app name, shortcut label and icon after installation. Is it possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19495998/change-app-name-shortcut-label-and-icon-after-installation-is-it-possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app's title stated in the manifest and cannot be changed during runtime. Android does not permit this.
You can, however, change the title of the app in the title bar via setTitle(name);

But the icon you can change:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19593601/2413972

Comment: As you wish. This is a common programming on android