# onTaskRemoved called after onCreate in started service on swipe-out from recent app list

Tags: android, android-service, kill-process

I have a service started from an Activity, the service is running fine `onCreate`, `onStartCommand` called properly. In settings-->running app its showing `1 process and 1 service`.
Now when I swipe out my application from apps recent list. The service recreates, In settings-->running app it shows `0 process and 1 service` `restarting...` And `onCreate`, `onStartCommand`, `onTaskRemoved` called.

Now the issue is in one app `onTaskRemoved` called immediately after swiping app out then `onCreate` called, and in other app `onTaskRemoved` takes time and called after `onCreate`.

Why this different behavior is there ? Any suggestion will help me. Please provide your comments and observations.

```
08-26 15:43:48.611: D/PassiveService(15359): PASS_IVE, onCreate...
08-26 15:43:48.611: I/PassiveService(15359): PASS_IVE, registerReceivers...
```

After swipe out

```
08-26 15:44:05.789: D/PassiveService(15499): PASS_IVE, onCreate...
08-26 15:44:05.809: I/PassiveService(15499): PASS_IVE, registerReceivers...
08-26 15:44:05.839: I/PassiveService(15499): PASS_IVE, onTaskRemoved...
```

Answer (score 2):

Calling **onTaskRemoved** of the running service(when app gets swiped out from recent apps) will be generally delayed **if we are performing any heavy UI related stuff or broadcasting messages to receivers in service**.

**E.g ,** Assume you are downloading the file of size 50MB from web server, so from web server everytime you are reading 1024bytes of stream data as buffer and that data you are writing to a file in device.

Meanwhile you are updating the progress to the UI thread which means every KB you are updating to the UI thread, this will cause the application to freeze.

So in between if you swipe-out from recent app list , then the system will try to stop the service but since the service is in-contact with the UI thread, the  system will be unable to stop that service, **but** it will create **new service** eventhough the old service is not yet stopped.

Once old service finishes the communication with the UI thread then onTaskRemoved() gets called and the old service will be stopped. The new service will be running in the background.

Comment: "So in between if you swipe-out from recent app list , then the system will try to stop the service but since the service is in-contact with the UI thread, the system will be unable to stop that service, but it will create new service eventhough the old service is not yet stopped." How that makes any sense? Why would it try to create new Service when the system wanted to stop it?

Comment: From what I noticed Service's in Android are just a mess, you have onDestroy in lifecycle, but can't rely on it. Sometimes it feels like a joke on developers. Missing clean up state, you can do things onPause but for most use cases its way too early.