# onTaskRemoved of a Android Service is never being called ! Why?

Tags: android, android-service

I am stuck with a issue from last 2 days, I want to hit a `api` and show user a `Toast` when user **swipe off** the app from Background Task, I found that from `service` it is possible as `onTaskRemoved` is called when app is removed from background.

Code :

**MyService.java**

```
public class MyService extends Service {

private static final String TAG = MyService.class.getSimpleName();
Handler mHandler;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mHandler = new Handler();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand: ");
    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new ToastPoP(MyService.this).showLongToast("Service started");
        }
    });

    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    Log.d(TAG, "onTaskRemoved: ");
    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(App.getInstance(), "Removed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // api call too
        }

    });
    // for kitket
    Intent restartService = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            this.getClass());
    restartService.setPackage(getPackageName());
    PendingIntent restartServicePI = PendingIntent.getService(
            getApplicationContext(), 1, restartService,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmService.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000, restartServicePI);

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy: ");
}
}
```

and in `Manifest` i have added this :

```
 <service
        android:name=".MyService"
        android:stopWithTask="false"
        >
    </service>
```

and started `service` in SplashScreen :

```
 Intent i = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
    this.startService(i);
```

Service is started well but `onTaskRemoved` is never called when i am removing app from Background. Why ? what i am doing wrong?

Note:

*And Interesting result is this i am able to get Toast in some device but not in most of the devices and all device's have OS- Android 5.0*

Comment: Just set android:stopWithTask="true" in your service tag inside Manifest.

Comment: @Radhey i have tried, it has no effect, service also destroyed with application

Comment: did you found solution finally or not ?

Comment: @himCream No :( not yet

Comment: is there any solution for this ?

Comment: @android_sh sorry no success yet

Comment: I think this could be the reason: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42120277/247013

Answer (score -3):

Try this one

```
<service
            android:name=".MyService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:stopWithTask="false" />
```

Just replace `Service.START_STICKY;` to `START_STICKY;`

And you will able to call `onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent)` once app removed/clear from recent app list.