# Service onTaskRemoved not call when kill app in some device

Tags: android, service

I have override `onTaskRemoved` in my `Service` but it never get called when I kill app in device `Xiaomi` but in `SamSung`, `Sony` it get called normally
( I don't set `ServiceInfo.FLAG_STOP_WITH_TASK` for my Service)

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
         super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
         Toast.makeText(this,"onTaskRemoved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         Log.i("TAG", "Task removed");
    }
}
```

I need detect when service stop to start service again because `START_STICKY` not working like [my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41627537/service-not-start-again-after-kill-app-even-use-start-sticky-in-some-device)

How can I handle this case. Any help or suggestion would be great appreciated?

Comment: the use brodcast receiver in ondestroy method and again start service

Comment: @Divyesh `onDestroy` will never call **in all device** when we kill app in recent app ^^

Comment: `onTaskRemoved` is not guaranteed to be called as I mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40072294/when-can-ontaskremoved-be-called/40072391#40072391) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35729654/whi%D1%81h-function-is-called-when-application-is-removed-from-task-manger/35729793#35729793). _"I need detect when service stop to start service again because `START_NOT_STICKY` not working..."_ No wonder it's not working, use [`START_STICKY`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY) instead.

Comment: Enable Autostart permission for your app in settings