# onTaskRemoved() doesn't work on Android 8.0 Oreo API level 26

Tags: android, kotlin, android-service, android-8.0-oreo, jobservice

On device with Android Oreo 8.0 (API level 26) `JobService.onTaskRemoved()` isn't called

- How to listen for such an event?

Code used which stopped working:

```
class TaskRemovalWatcherService: JobIntentService() {
    ...
    override fun onTaskRemoved(rootIntent: Intent?) {  
    //not called on Android Oreo

        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);   
        onAppRemovedFromRecentApps()
    }
}
```

When App-Task is removed from recent apps I need to

1. Stop a process
2. Finish 2nd AppTask

if AppTasks.size = 2 and 1 task is removed from recent apps, then process is NOT killed, because 2nd AppTask still in memory.

Update:

1. when use `JobIntentService.enqueueWork` then right after `JobIntentService.onHandleWork()` `JobIntentService.onDestroy()` is called
2. when use `JobService.schedule()` throws `IllegalArgumentException` when schadule job without constraints.

P.S. **The idea of checking each X seconds isTaskWasRemoved seems not a good one.**

Comment: are you using service class ?

Comment: you should use job scheduler

Comment: Thank you guys, JobService.onTaskRemoved() doesn't called

Comment: what is your requirement and post your code here

Comment: Goal: finish all AppTasks + stop process when App-Task is removed from  recent apps. 
I have 2 AppTasks: if AppTasks.size = 2 and 1 task is removed from recent apps, process is NOT killed, because 2nd AppTask still in memory.Goal is to finish all tasks + kill app process, when 1 task is removed.

Comment: alright dear let me check it

Answer (score 0):

You can override `JobService#onStop()` and then create a message and pass it to the other service, when the service receives that message you can clean up it's work and kill it.

Answer (score 0):

The expected behavior of `START_STICKY` might have changed due to custom implementation by device manufacturer or due to new implementation in android Oreo

You can use [`JobScheduler`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler) to monitor a service lifecycle after regular interval.
If service is destroyed, then you can perform your task in `onDestroy()` method just before service is actually being destroyed.

This will remove your dependency from `onTaskremoved()` method.

Please refer below question with similar problem
[onTaskRemoved() not getting called when Home press & kill the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49486656/ontaskremoved-not-getting-called-when-home-press-kill-the-app)