# React Native listen to removing app from recent list (android/ios)

Tags: react-native

How to listen when user remove app from recent list( android and ios)

I have to store some data

Comment: Just remove? or also kill app?

Comment: currently I want to listen in remove event and run some code, but kill event is good too

Comment: For this you will need background service

Comment: @ProllyGeek Could you explain more how to listen to that event on background service in react-native?

Comment: for example try this:https://github.com/jamesisaac/react-native-background-task

Comment: @ProllyGeek But this package just run some code at background...my main problem is how to listen when app remove from recent list and then I can run some code in call back of that event in background sevice

Comment: Yes, and there you will write native listeners for app close event (can be found on google dev, and apple dev) . For example because I am more into android:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568315/how-to-handle-code-when-app-is-killed-by-swiping-in-android