# Is it possible to keep an application running in background after being cleaned from recent apps?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm using **BackgroundMode** plugin in **Ionic 4** and it works fine when I minimize the app, but I clean it form recent apps it stops sending data. Is there any way to keep it running?

app.component.ts

```
  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
      this.backgroundMode.enable();
      this.backgroundMode.on('activate').subscribe(() => {
        console.log('activated background mode');
        this.backgroundMode.disableWebViewOptimizations();
      });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just did [some digging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54778793/ionic-3-4-how-to-stop-app-kill-on-swiping-from-recent-apps?rq=1).

It seems that there is a `manifest.xml` option for Android:

```
<service
    android:name="com.myapp.MyService"
    android:stopWithTask="false" />
```

I would check out the linked question and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568315/how-to-handle-code-when-app-is-killed-by-swiping-in-android) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for marking as answer. If it helped please consider upvoting as well, otherwise stackoverflow don't count it towards my Ionic4 badge.