# How to Send custom google Analytics event when user kills the application in Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I need to send google Analytics custom even when the user kills the application.

1. I tried Service.onTaskRemoved() but could not preserve Analytics object till this is called
2. I tried to send the event when the app goes to the background on pressing the back button, but this does not really solve the problem because I cannot track when the application goes to the background on pressing the home button.

Comment: Why do you need that? What information do you want to get from it?

Comment: @Ircover The client needs the information as to when the user kills the app

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568315/how-to-handle-code-when-app-is-killed-by-swiping-in-android

check this one