# Badges for android applications

Tags: android, widget, badge

I need to add a badge for any unread notification's in my android application. My research tells me that I need to use a widget for this purpose. I already have used a widget for this purpose, and I get a badge with a number whenever an event is received.

The problem I have is that I am unable to identify a way to replace the application icon with the widget. Is it possible in android at all? Is there any workaround for this?

Thanks!

Comment: check this https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger

Comment: Isn't that an in app badge? Would that work for an icon too?

Comment: Maybe this link helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android