# How to maintain two APK on play store of same application

Tags: android, apk

I want to keep live two versions of same application on play store, one is lite version and another is gold (both versions are paid). But when user move from lite version to gold then lite version should need to update by gold version.

I saw some applications on plays store which maintain two package name on play store one is free & one is paid, and for paid version user need to download free app first then they can able to download/updated paid version. So my question is how this is happen, what should I need to do this?

Please help me to decide my application approach to do this.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you, there's plenty of guides out there :)

http://www.donnfelker.com/howto-android-full-and-lite-versions/

Comment: I go through your link, where we need to create two application and one common jar file, but due to this two application icon are present on our device and I want to replace/update first application(lite version) with other(gold version).

Comment: This will help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android