# How to change app name with an image, android

Tags: android, android-imageview

I am new to android application development. When I create a test app. I see the app name and logo by default. To change that we can go to androidmanifest.XML file and change it.

My question is, I want an image to be fixed in the place of the app name displaying in the top of the app.

Kindly help me.

Comment: for that, you need to change ic_launcher image in drawable folder.

Comment: replace ic_launcher image in res folder

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20851274/how-to-change-launcher-icon-and-its-label-from-the-application

Comment: you can't do that, but instead you can change app icon/logo but the above will be definitely the name of the app along side with the app logo

Comment: [tag:logo] is a programming language.  Please don't use it's tag for questions relating to graphical logos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get result try this;

**In code:**

```
getActionBar().setTitle("");
getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.your_icon);
```

**In XML:**

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity" 
       android:icon="@drawable/your_icon" 
       android:label="" />
```

To enable the back button in your app use:

```
 getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
 getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change name of application from values/strings.xml for ex: `<string name="app_name">your app name</string>` for more: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

and you can change image with create new icon_launcher for good ex: [Set icon for android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350624/set-icon-for-android-application)