# Can I set android launcher icon in Main Activity

Tags: android, icons, android-manifest, launch

We always know set android:icon in Manifest can set icon and logo,

```
android:icon="drawable resource"
```

Can I set logo icon in Main Activity with Java code?

thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20851334/2777227) could help you.
Extract from [mike yaworski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2554605/mike-yaworski)'s answer:

> Summary:
>
> `android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"` determines your launcher icon, so
>   just add images to the drawable folders and change `ic_launcher` to
>   whatever the name of image is that you want to be the icon.
>
> `android:label="@string/app_name"` determines your "label" so just look
>   for `app_name` (because the label is referenced to `@string/app_name`) in
>   your `strings.xml` file and change the contents of app_name.