# How can we change android application icon dynamically in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-manifest

I know that same kind of question has been asked for activity icon, but my question is little bit different.

I just wanted to know whether we can set the application icon programmatically, I am not asking to change, I am just asking for setting it. I hope I am clear.

```
<application android:icon="drawable resource"> </application>
```

In the above example I am setting it in manifest file, but instead of manifest can I set it through java code.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply blackbelt.Can you please provide some official link which says it is not possible...

Comment: please have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android

Comment: you can take a look the commonsware's answer in the link above. I did not find nothing official but the public api does not provide a method to change the icon programmatically

Comment: @blackbelt m sure there is a way to do it, because one of the apps on google play store (if m not wrong, the screen recorder) has a way of changing the application icon

Comment: @TheUnknown probably there is some hack

Comment: @blackbelt yeah could be..

Comment: Could it be locating, loading, making changes and saving the manifest file using code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can read here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html the default's app icon is set in the manifest. As manifest is located in the app's /root it cannot be modified, so there's no way to do it.
You may consider that if you could change it while the app is running, changes wouldn't be saved in the manifest.