# Android - Adding option to switch app icon

Tags: android, icons

I am making an app in which I would like to let the users to choose from a predefined list of icons and use the selected icon as the application's launcher icon.

I saw this feature in some version of the SuperSU app

How to do that?

Comment: Could you be more specific to explain better your question?

Comment: Is there a way  so that users can change the app's icon from a given set of icons?

Comment: Specify the OP talks about the launcher icon.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to do it dynamically because the icon is set in the [AndroidManifest.xml](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html), and it is located on the root folder.

You could read:

- [Is there any way to dynamically change an Android app icon like Calendar app does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34592230/is-there-any-way-to-dynamically-change-an-android-app-icon-like-calendar-app-doe)
- [How can we change android application icon dynamically in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21108611/how-can-we-change-android-application-icon-dynamically-in-android)