# Change icon of app

Tags: icons, android, launching-application, android-icons

I want to change the application icon using button to change it.
I've seen apps like [Whatsapp Plus](http://www.whatsapp-plus.net/download.php) and [Audio Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smartanuj.hideitpro) does this. 
In Audio manager the apps name, title and even the launch screen(may be Main Activity) can be changed. 
I want to implement this facility in my App. I'm developing a secret/hacking app.

I've searched in this site many times. Similar questions are very less and those say it's not possible. Then how come the above two apps. 
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1103027/3416031) is the only similar question I've come across.
Please help

Comment: You mean to replace the app icon with image from gallery?

Comment: No, I mean to change the app or icon to completely newer one. For eg. the Audio Manager app has an option under settings to 'Change the disguise screen' then if we select the new icon of app then the app and screen ui will restart and the audio application completely changes to a joke app. The icons are in-built. It just changes when we select the icon we want. The only place where the original app icon and name shows is under system settings apps.

Comment: Yes I get it. What would I do is: when the user click "change icon" button, just rename the icon from drawable from example.png to ic_launcher.png and current ic_launcher.png to example.png. You would have to do it in all folders (drawable-hdpi,...). Is this what you want?

Comment: May be it will do. But I don't know exactly. Help me with codes. I'll try it out and give you a reply

Comment: You can also checkout Audio Manager free version to understand want I want.

Comment: have you tried this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android