# How to tag application Icon to "new" when something new is uploaded in server?

Tags: android

I am developing wallpaper application in android. Application fetch wallpapers form server and display it on gridview.

Now all I want to do is when I upload new wallpapers on server, the application Icon should get tagged with "new" and when user launch an application, tag should get disappear and application Icon should appear as it before.

Any help will highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/q/1103027/1396879, I think it can help you to do this ;)

Comment: also look here: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html

Comment: Thanks OBuiron and Budius

Answer (score 0):

There is no public API for doing this, although some launchers achieve it with their private API.